# Git installation issue in Mountain Lion (OS X 10.8)

Tags: macos, git, github, osx-mountain-lion

I just installed new Mountain Lion (OS X 10.8) on my MacBook Air and then trying to install and configure git on my mac. But, surprisingly git was not being opened or installed ! Why it is not being opened or installed?

Comment: Why are you installing your own git when it comes with the Xcode command-line tools?

Comment: Please describe how you are installing git. From source? Homebrew? etc.

Comment: Probably be better off using brew to get it, and keep it up to date.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is due to a new security mechanism named Gatekeeper in Mountain Lion, where it is default to prevent applications from being opened when they do not come from the Mac App Store or from a verified source.

To solve the problem :

1. Go to `"System Preferences" -> “Security & Privacy” -> “General”` tab
2. Find `“Allow applications downloaded from:”` in the bottom half of the window.
3. Choose `“Anywhere”`

That's it ! You are done! Now, you can easily install and configure git on your newly installed Mountain Lion (OS X 10.8).

Comment: +1, good tip in general, though you shouldn't need to install Git yourself on 10.8...

Comment: Yeah, but it may be useful when installing other programs on 10.8 as well !

Comment: Installing from source might be attractive if you don't want to deal with XCode's atrocious 1.65GB download size.  (If you're not an iOS or OS X developer, there's not much reason for XCode.)